# Return Table Row number on Cell Change VBA

Tags: vba, excel-2010

Totally new to VBA. I am trying to identify the row in a table in which a cell change has occurred. If I change one of the cells in the last column of table, I want to pass the row along to a macro.

I found the basis for the change code in another answer, and added my table range:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Intersect(Target, Range("Table4[Ready]")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False 'to prevent endless loop

    MsgBox Target.address

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

How can I find that target.address is row 5 of table 4?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to work:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Range("Table4[Ready]")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    MsgBox Target.Row - Range("Table4[Ready]").Row + 1
End Sub
```

Comment: It works because the **Row** of a piece of a single column is the same as the **Row** of the top element of that piece.  In our case the piece excludes the *Header*